# Google-like name autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In my web-interface I want to apply Google-like autocomplete used in Google+. The one where you start to type email address of the user and it will fill the field with the name, adding a nice cross button on the right to delete what you just typed. It there a jQuery plug in that implies this functionality?

Thank you in advance.

PS. Just noticed! the same one as used on StackOverflow when adding the tags for the question ;)

PPS. Thank you guys. What I was really looking for is something like

http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/

http://devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/

http://ajaxdump.com/?KR5t42gD

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

It's a default jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice plugin on their own website, take a look here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

They also added a nice example.

This is also one that I like: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm